# Как проверить учет регистра для отдельной директории? С++

Tags: c++, windows, файловая-система

Все мы знаем, что в Windows файловая система case-insensetive, то есть не учитывает регистр и пути `kek/lol` и `KEK/lOl` - одно и то же (в Linux же наоборот). Однако с появлением wsl и Windows 10 у нас появилась возможность задать имя каталога, как case-sensetive. И это начинает приводить к проблемам. Мне требуется возможность узнать как учитывается регистр для конкретного каталога.

Например есть путь:

```
std::string path {"E:/Foo/Bar/main.cpp"};
```

Во избежание ошибок с регистром мне нужно пройтись по всему пути и для каждой директории (Foo и Bar в данном случае) сохранить ее статус учета регистра. Например директория Foo - case-sensetive, а Bar - case-insensetive. Как мне узнать учитывается ли регистр для данной директории или нет? Нужно как-то опросить файловую систему, но я не могу найти ничего нужного. Желательно, чтобы способ работал и на Linux, и на Windows, если такой способ вообще существует

Comment: *"Все мы знаем, что в Windows файловая система case-insensetive"* - нет, в windows актуальные файловые системы являются case-sensetive. А вот WinAPI позволяет обращаться к ним, как к case-preserving.

Comment: @user7860670 как же case-sensetive, если `C:/Windows` и `C:/windows` - одни и те же директории?

Comment: Я же написал **WinAPI позволяет обращаться к ним, как к case-preserving** Но имена в файловой системе всегда чувствительны к регистру. И хранится всегда имя в точности с теми регистрами букв, которые били использованы при его создании. Между прочим, case-preserving API и для linux удобно использовать, хотя там они как-то не особо распространены.